# Iterate over a collection of keys stored in the localStorage via jStorage library

Tags: javascript, local-storage, jstorage

How to iterate over a collection of keys stored in the localStorage using `jStorage` API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.jStorage.index()
```

Returns all the keys currently in use as an array.

```
var index = $.jStorage.index();
console.log(index); // ["key1","key2","key3"]
```